# Flutter layout style change according to api response

Tags: android, flutter, dart, user-interface, flutter-dependencies

I want to change my layout according to an api response. For example if the api response return gridview I want to display my data in gridview and If it return horizontal listview then i want to have my data in listview format.

So my question is which is the best way to implement? I have tried listview builder but it is not working.

I will have my layout style in my api response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use flutter's Futurebuilder for this.

Future builder will build the widget according to the Api response.
Here is an example of the Future builder.

```
return FutureBuilder(
  future: apiCall(),
  builder: (context, response){
    if(response.hasData){
      var data = response.data;
      if(data["layout"] == "gridview") return GridView.builder();
      else return ListView.builder();
    }else return Container();
  },
);
```

In this way you will be able to build your layout according to API response.

and as always..
**Happy Coding**

Comment: Thanks i Will try this. But can you explain how can I integrate this with lazy loading or infinite scroll where I will receive the api response and build this layout according to the response.

Comment: You can do the lazy loading the very similar way you are doing till now. It won't affect the loading process. Also if you can attach your code then it will be helpful for us to understand what you trying to acheive.

Comment: Also if this answer helped you then don`t forget to upvote & accept this answer. :-)

Comment: Hi I have attach the code in question.  I have a column that have couple of elements inside it I have set the layout of these element using the future builder technique and it works. Now i want to add such elements in my column when i scroll down and reach bottom.

Comment: Thanks for the attachment. You can achieve the lazy loading easily using **ScrollController** and add elements using extend after in scroll controller. If you want a detailed answer just open one more question asking this and mention the link here. i will give you a detailed answer there.